# UITableView custom cell can't scroll fluent,as database block my main thread

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I used multi column tableView !For one screen I have 16 cells,and If I have 3000 data ,and I got the thumbnail image from database( I use the open source -FMDB),and when load this table,I open only one thread to download the thumbnail, and save to database.

When the cell is visible,I got thumbnail from db,if it had been downloaded.
But I found that I got data from database is very slow,about 0.15~1.3 seconds for one cell, and I have 16 cell for one screen. So it block my main thread?

Any suggestion to help me solve the problem?

Thanks in advance.

This is the code I get thumbnail~

```
   -(NSData *)queryVideoSmallThumbnailData:(NSString *)theSourceUrl
    {
        if(theSourceUrl == nil)
            return nil;
    NSString *query = @"SELECT SMALL_THUMBNAIL_DATA FROM FIELDS WHERE SOURCE_URL";
    query = [query stringByAppendingString:@"=\""];
    query = [query stringByAppendingString:theSourceUrl];
    query = [query stringByAppendingString:@"\""];

    NSData * data = nil;

    FMResultSet *rs = [database executeQuery:query];
    while ([rs next]) 
    {
    data = [rs dataForColumn:@"SMALL_THUMBNAIL_DATA"];
    break;
    }

    [rs close];

    return data;
    }
```

This is the table view refresh image code.

```
    image = [thumbCache getThumbFromCache:record.sourceUrl]
     if (image == nil)
        {
            DBVideoThumb *thumbDB = [[DBManager getInstance] getDBVideoThumb];
            NSData *data = [thumbDB queryVideoSmallThumbnailData:record.sourceUrl];
            image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            if (image != nil)
                [thumbCache addThumbToCache:record.sourceUrl image:image];
        }
```

Comment: See if this helps you: http://stavash.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/advanced-issues-asynchronous-uitableviewcell-content-loading-done-right/

Comment: Please copy and paste code - snapshots don't help too much.

Comment: @Stavash Thanks for your link. But my issue is that query database block my thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of your database may affect your query speed. So, when your table View dragging,you may change your thumbnail to small one. a blur one, as small as possible.

Create a Index for your database as can improve your query speed from n to log2 n.
For example :Create index urlIndex on Fields(url);

Comment: Yeah, I believe that dababase size effect the query operation. But why my ipod4 is fluent? ipad 1 and ipod 4, which one performs better ? ipod.May be some other factors I am doing wrong!

Comment: iPod 4 and iPad share same A4 CPU. So the difference of performance here mostly points to a memory issue.

Comment: Thank you so eager to help me，I have decided to accept your answer！Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using this [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) I suggest you (re)read the instructions. The author points out that using a single instance of FMBD on multiple threads is a bad idea. This is a common problem for anything that has to maintain data integrity.

Assuming you are using FMDB, have you tried creating multiple instances of FMDB on the same store, one for each thread? You can apply this to other answers posted here, inside an asynchronous block. Remember to close each instance when you're done and check that there is a lock on the database to ensure atomic writes.

If you're open to other solutions, Core Data might be of use if you're modelling an object graph you'd like to persist.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem during my app development but I used following code to solve this issue. May be its help you. If you get any trouble let me know.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^(void) {

      NSData *imageData ;

      imageData = [UICommonUtils imageDataFromString:profile.Photo];

      dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {

           if([imageData length] > 1) {

              cell.ProfileImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

            } else {

               cell.ProfileImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:kDefaultProfileImage];

            }
       });

      imageData = nil;
});
```

Comment: It crashed in thread. The FMDatabase <FMDatabase: 0x1337550> is currently in use. I get data from database.

Comment: using a single instance of FMBD on multiple threads is a bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

I think [UIImage imageWithData:filename] may be a cause. its performance, as I believe, is far lower than imageNamed:. or imagewithContentOfFile:. My solution is saving it as file in another thread, then show it in main thread after saving done. if the video is not changed, next time will directly show file without query database.

Comment: I             NSData *data = [thumbDB queryVideoSmallThumbnailData:record.sourceUrl];